# is there any method to split list of string to list of string where each sublist's sum of elements size less than N?

Tags: python, string, list, algorithm, kotlin

I want to convert following list

```
["abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "a"]
```

to this list

```
[["abcd", "abcd"], ["abcd", "abcd"], ["abcd", "abcd", "a"]]
```

the sum of the lengths of the sublist elements must be less than 10

in other words i want to add string into sublist while it sum of size of elements less than 10

Here's my attempt

```
val list = listOf("abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "a")

var currentGroupSize = 0
var sublist = mutableListOf<String>()
var result = mutableListOf<List<String>>()

for (element in list) {
    if (element.length + currentGroupSize < 10) {
        sublist.add(element)
        currentGroupSize += element.length
    } else {
        result.add(sublist)
        sublist = mutableListOf(element)
        currentGroupSize = element.length
    }
}

println(result)
```

Comment: Your question should explain what you want to achieve, however providing solely input and desired output is not sufficient to understand this problem.

Comment: Simplest solution is to put each element into a sublist alone.

Comment: haha, clever considering the problem statement @KellyBundy

Comment: Why is this tagged python AND kotlin? Are you expecting code in either language?

Comment: The problem is a bit understated. What if a single element is longer than the limit? Should it be skipped completely?

Comment: All elements cant be bigger that limit by default

Comment: Also, please try to show your attempt at solving this problem so we can help you with the details in the exact place(s) where you're stuck. If we write the whole algorithm for you, it won't help you much in the future

Comment: *All elements cant be bigger that limit by default* - does that mean that they are guaranteed to all be smaller than the limit in the input, or that the code should fail if it's the case, or that they are not allowed to be there in the output?

Comment: yes, it mean that they are guaranteed to all be smaller than the limit in the input,

Comment: Your attempt looks pretty good! What's wrong with it?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](/questions/63633977/kotlin-how-to-split-list-of-strings-based-on-the-total-length-of-characters)?

Comment: Why does your output contain six "abcd" when your input only contains five?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val list = listOf("abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "a")
val maxCountOfChars = 10

val result = mutableListOf<MutableList<String>>()

for (item in list) {

  if (result.isEmpty()) {
    result.add(mutableListOf(item))
  } else {
    if (item.length <= maxCountOfChars - result.last().sumOf { it.length }) {
      result.last().add(item)
    } else {
      result.add(mutableListOf(item))
    }
  }
  
}

println(result)   // Prints:   [[abcd, abcd], [abcd, abcd], [abcd, a]]
```

This is a more concise solution using *fold*:

```
val list = listOf("abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "abcd", "a")
val maxCountOfChars = 10

val result = list
  .fold(mutableListOf<MutableList<String>>()) { acc, s ->
    if (acc.isEmpty() || s.length > maxCountOfChars - acc.last().sumOf { it.length }) {
      acc.add(mutableListOf(s))
    } else {
      acc.last().add(s)
    }
    acc
  }

println(result)   // Prints:   [[abcd, abcd], [abcd, abcd], [abcd, a]]
```